# Official Docker image says docker not running?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I perform the following docker commands in the following order:

```
docker pull docker

docker run -ti <imgId>
```

https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Now I am inside the "docker" image for Docker

Now suppose I create a temp folder and download a Dockerfile

```
mkdir temp

cd temp

curl <dockerfile>

docker build .
```

It will tell me `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

This means that the `docker` service needs to be started, but as the official docker image comes on **alpine linux**, commands like `service/systemctl` are not available, so we must perform `apk add openrc --no-cache` to access these.

After I install it, I still cannot start the docker service.

Performing `system docker start` says that it cannot find `docker` as a service?

### `service: service docker does not exist`

Eventually I want to build this via Jenkins.

[image]

In the build step, I perform `Execute Shell`

```
if [ -f "Dockerfile" ]; then
    echo "Dockerfile exists ... removing it"
    rm Dockerfile
fi

wget <dockerFile url>


docker build .
```

I purposely don't do the `openrc` on Jenkins since I want to test locally first

Comment: Is your Jenkins inside a container?

Comment: Yes, my Jenkins pulls the docker image from our proxy

Comment: @ps4, I added an image for your preference

Comment: To a first approximation, commands like `service` and `systemctl` just don't work at all in Docker.  Running Docker as a container is a particularly advanced setup, and generally disrecommended; usually you'd configure Jenkins to use the host's Docker socket.

Comment: Using Jenkins to use the dockers host socket requires that the Jenkins service be installed on the Linux Slave, which is not the approach we are going for. I'm wondering what I am doing wrong here though? The official image should have docker installed

Comment: Using the `docker` image is probably wrong.  The [Docker Hub page for the image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) says so too, though not quite as bluntly.

Comment: It is not recommended, but it is a requirement here

Answer (score 0):

The image you're pulling here (with the `latest` tag) does not contain the docker daemon. It's meant to be used as the docker client. What you want is to first get the docker daemon running with the image tagged `dind` (docker in docker).

```
docker network create dind
docker run --privileged --name docker --network dind -v docker-client-certs:/certs/client -d docker:dind
```

To verify it started up and works, you can check the logs.

```
docker logs docker
```

Now you can use a client container to connect to the daemon. This is how you connect interactively to the shell, like you wanted to:

```
docker run -ti --network dind -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs -v docker-client-certs:/certs/client:ro docker
```

Docker commands should work inside this container. If you do `docker version`, you should see the versions of both the client and the server.

Note the two containers share the same network (some examples online feature links, but those are deprecated). They also share some of the TLS certs, which are generated when starting up the `dind` image.